# Unable to get salesforce access token, When use Enterprise Edition as a destination

Tags: integration

I have a three org.
a) Source org(A)(Developer org)
b) Destination org(Developer org)(B)
c) Destination org(Enterprise Edition)

When i try to get access token in source org (A) for Destination org(Developer org(B)) This is working fine.

When i try to get access token in source org (A) for Destination org(Enterprise Edition(c)) This Not working why.

What is the validity of accsess token in salesforce.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I am getting Bad request error.

Comment: Can you frame your question in better way. You say developer to developer is working but developer to enterprise not working?

Comment: Hello Ashwani sir , I have a three org first is Mddev second is UAT and third is Packaging org. Uat org as a Enterprise edition I am doing integration in Mddev org (Developer org) with Uat org. i made a connected application in uat org and use it in Mddev to get access token now i am not able to access token for uat. While i got access token and record for packaging org.Where i am wrong.

Comment: I am getting below error.@@{"error_description":"authentication failure","error":"invalid_grant"}

Comment: @RavikantKedia grant_type must be `authorization_code` in url

Answer (score 1):

Authentication URL should look like this:

```
http://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
?
grant_type=authorization_code
&code=aPrwsmIExxx%3D%3D
&client_id=3MVyyyyyyyyy
&client_secret=1950000000000000
&redirect_uri=apex/vforcepage
```

Http method should be `POST`